# UIDocumentPickerViewController.ModalPresentationStyle can't be changed in iOS 16.1

Tags: c#, swift, xamarin.ios, xcode14

I've got a app that depends on Xamarin.IOS.
It at some point can display a document picker as a popover.
After updating to XCode14 and doing a build for iOS16 I found the document picker was displaying incorrectly (In its FormSheet style rather than in the Popover style).

The reason for this seems to be that attempting to change ModalPresentationStyle is silently failing and remaining as the same default value - FormSheet.

Reproduced it outside of the app in a simple test app with a single button click handler.
Here I'd expect the ModalPresentationStyle to change or at least throw some sort of an error if not supported. Instead, it silently remains as UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet.

```
partial void BtnClick(UIKit.UIButton sender)
{
    var allowedUtis = new List<string>() { ".txt" };
    var documentPicker = new UIDocumentPickerViewController(
        allowedUtis.ToArray(), 
        UIDocumentPickerMode.Import);

    var previousValue = documentPicker.ModalPresentationStyle;
    documentPicker.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover;
    Debug.WriteLine($"Changed from {previousValue} to {documentPicker.ModalPresentationStyle}");

    if (documentPicker.PopoverPresentationController != null)
    {
        documentPicker.PopoverPresentationController.SourceView = sender;
        documentPicker.PopoverPresentationController.SourceRect = sender.Bounds;
        documentPicker.PopoverPresentationController.PermittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up;
    }

    PresentModalViewController(documentPicker, true);
}
```

Also reproduced this same behaviour in a test app in swift to check it wasn't Xamarin.IOS that was the problem. Again here the value of modalPresentationStyle remains as .formSheet (2).

```
let supportedTypes: [UTType] = [UTType.audio]
let pickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: supportedTypes, asCopy: true) 1017

print(String(describing: pickerViewController.modalPresentationStyle));
pickerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
print(String(describing: pickerViewController.modalPresentationStyle));

self.present(pickerViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
```

This didn't happen on XCode13 but does on XCode14.01 on an 8th gen iPad running iOS 16.1.

Can't be reproduced on XCode14.01 with a simulator running iOS 16.0.

Has the expected behavior changed? I can't seem to find anything in the release notes of documentation about this.

Comment: Strange with the new versions, and open-picker modality? I use a sample code with
`documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext`
and it worked before. Now it works initially, but if I run `UIActivityViewController()` to save file, then Open picker opens but doesn't take command. I have looked for errors in the `UIActivityViewController()` code, nothing works. If you remove the modalPresentationStyle line, the problems are gone (default is OK). I don't experience any problems anymore but it is very strange (and wonder why it was in the sample code??)?

Comment: Same issue. Did you manage to find the solution @JanBergström?

Comment: Sorry I did not put the solution here, finding it, now slightly forgotten.  Haven't touched the Xcode since December. 
However I think the issue is folder privileges (had similar problems and solution in Android). I think the solution is saving all files in the programs own storage and then call for sharing it with the OS file handler, instead of getting the file name and save it directly from the program. The OS file handler has all the privileges. I also had an open last file feature and (in Android at least) is not possible except in the program storage, so i store a copy there for that.

Comment: @Zenchovey I am facing similar issue. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @user15077356 Sorry no, we ended up just accepting that on this version it would fallback to displaying using the formSheet style rather than spending any more time on it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same basic issue recently myself. The solution is to setup the `popoverPresentationController` after you present the modal view controller.

```
let supportedTypes: [UTType] = [UTType.audio]
let pickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: supportedTypes, asCopy: true) 1017

print(String(describing: pickerViewController.modalPresentationStyle));
pickerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
print(String(describing: pickerViewController.modalPresentationStyle));

self.present(pickerViewController, animated: true)

pickerViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
pickerViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
pickerViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .up
```

The view controller's `popoverPresentationController` is `nil` before the call to `present`. At least that is the case under iOS 16.

While I didn't test this specifically with `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, this solution worked for a general modal view controller I was trying to present. The view controller would appear as a form sheet, despite being set as a popover, if the `popoverPresentationController` was setup before the call to `present` instead of after.

Comment: Thanks @HangerRash, that's good to know. I tried this quickly with a custom UIViewController instantiated from the Storyboard and was able to change the modalPresentationStyle. So, I think this problem might be specific to the UIDocumentPickerViewController. There could be some other built in controllers like this that are also affected, will check tomorrow.

Comment: @Zenchovey I just did a test and I had no trouble showing a `UIDocumentPickerViewController` as a popover. My test was with a native iOS app written in Objective-C running on an iPad simulator with iOS 16.0 using Xcode 14.0.1.

Comment: Thanks, that's helped narrow this down a bit further. I can't reproduce on the iOS 16.0 simulator using XCode 14.01 either. I've getting this issue on 16.1 iOS physical iPad 8th Gen device. Will update the question to be more specific.